# How to remove substring of value of a specific field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, substring, field

I have the following mongo document:

```
{   Name: Peter,   
    Email: peter@mail.com,   
    EmailSuffix: peter@mail.com
}
```

I want to remove the substring before "@" of "EmailSuffix" field in all documents of the collection, so that the result will be:

```
{   Name: Peter,   
    Email: peter@mail.com,   
    EmailSuffix: @mail.com
}
```

I  have tried the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  {
       $match: { EmailSuffix: { $regex: /.+?(?=@)/ } }
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          EmailSuffix: { $split: [ "$EmailSuffix", "?" ] } 
      } 
  }
] ).forEach( doc => db.collection.updateMany( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { EmailSuffix:     doc.EmailSuffix[0] } } )`
```

But it doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$indexOfCP` to locate the first `@`. Then use `$substrCP` to do usual substring extraction.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "EmailSuffix": {
        "$substrCP": [
          "$EmailSuffix",
          {
            "$indexOfCP": [
              "$EmailSuffix",
              "@"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$strLenCP": "$EmailSuffix"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mMmk3hlNQjB)